# Do I need to write seperate APIs endpoint for each user role?

Tags: php, api, laravel

I have users into my app with two different roles, Student and Admin. Each user has a team_id field reference which tells the user which team it belongs. In this case my db consists of these tables : users,teams.

And to show a team details I have an API like below:
GET: api/teams/{team_id}

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $team = $this->teamService->findById($id);
        if ($team) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Success', 'success' => true, 'status' => 200, 'data' => $team]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error', 'success' => true, 'status' => 404, 'data' => null]);
        }
    }
```

Well this is for admin only as the $id is passed as an argument into the url, that means only admin can put any $id, while the normal user the id has to be automatically associated depending what team they belong(so in this case I want to show the team details for the team they belong).

so in this case my api should look like this:
GET: api/teams

```
public function show()
        {
            $team = $this->teamService->findById(Auth->user->team_id); //associate the team id for user logged in
            if ($team) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Success', 'success' => true, 'status' => 200, 'data' => $team]);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Error', 'success' => true, 'status' => 404, 'data' => null]);
            }
        }
```

So my final question is, is there any way that I can put this in one place for both roles.. so there will not be duplicate functions for different roles.

What should the API be look like in this case?

Thanks

Comment: can't you just use an if statment? if `if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){$team = $this->teamService->findById($id);} else { the other query}`

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja, I was thinking the same way, but if it's normal user, why do I need to pass a $id on the url, I mean the id on the url seems useless, and should I always pass it null if its normal user?

Comment: then you can use a middlaware, check if the user is an admin if yes -> redirect to a route restricted to admins with the id(using a middleware too) or redirect to a route for a normal user without need for adding the id to url

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to write seperate APIs endpoint for each user role?

No, definitely not.

> What should the API be look like in this case?

There is no "right" answer, but here are two ideas:

1) The User object should have links to your team object:

```
{ name: "bob", team_link: "/team/3" }
```

Then your `/team/:id` route should check "If you are not the admin user, give a 404 if user is not on this team."

2) If you *really* think a user needs to get their team info as it's own call, you can have a `/team` route. But the above is more standard. Or, serve a link to the real team object. (Why? Because it makes caching easier down the road.)

Comment: Are u saying the API should be looking like this: teams/{id}, right, if so, what should I pass as id in case I call from normal user, should I pass as null into the url? so the call will be: teams/null? this seems quite odd for me. Please if you could explain your first option more? thnx I appreciate that!

Comment: Yes, Option #1 is "teams/{id}". I'm saying some other API call should tell the user the specific URL to the team they are on. (for example, if the user fetches their own object, or maybe fetching some other state, it has a link to your team).  .. On the other hand, if "get my team data" is the very first API call, then you can have a "/team" route.

Comment: so again we having two routes, right? /team and /team/{id}? one for normal user and one for admin? I am not quite sure if I understood you...

Comment: You can have 2 routes, but it's *better not to*. For example, when the user logs in, you could **tell** them "your Team route is `/team/432`". The client stores that locally and remembers it when it wants to look up team info. The server would still have security checks ("do you own this team, or are you an admin?"), but then you don't need multiple routes to the same bit of data.